# Laravel 5 Ajax Request Showing 500 Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I am trying to post data to a function in a controller using a form via ajax
My code is :   `<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>` on the top of the page and ajax code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
});


$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('save', {name:'name anything'}, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

My route looks like

```
Route::post('/page/save', [
        'uses'=>  'BackEnd\PagesController@store'
]);
```

But I am getting the following error in my console

```
500 Internal Server Error
```

This is what I have in my controller:

```
if(Request::ajax()) {
            $data = Input::all();
            print_r($data);
            die();
}
```

Comment: There must be some error on php side. Add more php code.

Comment: I have only used code mentioned above nothing else @sgtBOSE

Comment: Have you check the network tab in console for the request? On which path it is requesting?

Comment: it is requesting in the correct path I think the problem is in my php code above as soon as I remove it everything works fine@sgtBOSE

Comment: Can you show the code of `store` method?

Comment: that is all I have used in store method right now I think the problem exists when I use the if(Request::ajax()) condition which gives me error but when I dont use it everything works fine@sgtBOSE

Comment: I think it might be `Request` or `Input`. Add the code of controller. Have you used them or injected them?

Comment: I have used them @sgtBOSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add - `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` before the controller class starts.

Implement dependency injecting - `public function store(Request $request)` to the method.

And intead of `$data = Input::all();` try with - `$data = $request::input('name');`

Hope the problem will be solved.

The controller should look like -

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class PagesController extends Controller {

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()) {
        $data = $request->input('name');
        print_r($data);
        die();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the exact error from firebug Net panel where you can choose "Open Response in New Tab" . This shows you the Laravel error message.

Similar way of checking the response content exists also in Chrome.